# Добавление JTabbedPane ниже JMenuBar

Tags: java, swing

интересует следующий вопрос, начал писать текстовый редактор на java и хотел сделать поддержку возможностей открытия одновременно нескольких файлов. Нашел, что можно для этого использовать JTabbedPane. Попытался встроить в своё приложение и столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Как можно увеличить размер контейнера, в который будет вложено содержимое.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тоесть чтобы JTextArea растянулся на всю оставшуюся часть окна.

Создание TabbedPane

```
Font fontPaneText = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 12);
choiceFile = new JTabbedPane(SwingConstants.NORTH_EAST, SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
choiceFile.setFont(fontPaneText);
```

Добавление на форму

```
container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
container.add(choiceFile, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
container.add(bar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Добавление вкладки происходит при нажатии кнопки Open из пункта меню File.

```
JTextArea area = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(res));
choiceFile.addTab(String.valueOf(workFile.getName()), area);
```

Comment: container.add(choiceFile, BorderLayout.LINE_START);  -- здесь должно быть BorderLayout.CENTER, чтобы занимать все доступную область окна.
new JTabbedPane(SwingConstants.NORTH_EAST, SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT) -- зачем SwingConstants.NORTH_EAST? По смыслу JTabbedPane.TOP должно быть, заголовки табов были сверху.

Comment: Спасибо, просто ранее, когда у меня было еще основное поле с JTextArea видимо происходило наложение и вкладок не было видно при выставленном SwingConstants.TOP, а сейчас всё выставил как Вы сказали и всё заработало как надо)